# Nadaraya Watson Bandwidth-Variance

Tags: cross-validation, nadaraya-watson

I'm working with the Nadaraya Watson estimator and calculate the optimal bandwidth h with leave one out cross validation.

Now I'd like to get the variance of h (not the variance of the NW estimator). Is this possible? Can anyone recommend literature?

Answer (score -1):

h is bandwidth and a single value(for uni-variate case). How it is possible to calculate a variance of a single value?
Even for multivariate case, bandwidth is single for every input variable. Suppose you have 5 variable so you got 5 bandwidths but every bandwidth is for each variable.

Comment: Meanwhile i found a Bayesian approach where you use the Metropolis Hastings algorithm. With this approach you can get a variance (and intervals).

Comment: Bayesian approach for what? To calculate bandwidth or in NW..........???

Comment: Food for thought: The sample mean is also only a single value yet people find a variance for it all the time

Comment: @einar that is mean of different samples.